# How to get make to process multiple audio files

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a part of my make file which does speech to text conversion. It works great on every mp3 file in the directory.

```
%.txt : %.mp3
    $(WS) $(FLAGS) ./$<
```

But the software would also just as happily work with .wav .m4a files etc. I spend a lot of time converting things into mp3. Is there any way to process lots of audio files the same way? Something like below (which doesn't work)

```
%.txt : %.mp3 %.wav %.m4a 
    $(WS) $(FLAGS) ./$<
```

Post of complete modified Make file

```
.SUFFIXES : .txt .m4a .mp3 .wav
SOURCES := $(wildcard  *.m4a)
TEXT := $(wildcard  *.txt)
OBJ := $(subst m4a,txt,$(SOURCES))
WS = whisper

FLAGS = --device cuda:1 --model small 
.PHONY: test clean imported

define template =
%.txt: %.$(1)
        $(WS) $(FLAGS) $$<
endef
$(foreach extension,mp3 wav m4a,$(eval $(call template,$(extension))))

BIN := $(wildcard *.mp3 *.wav *.m4a)
TXT := $(addsuffix .txt,$(basename $(BIN)))

all: $(TXT)


clean :
    rm *~ *.json  *.srt  *.tsv  *.vtt 

split: $(TEXT)
    awk -v RS="[.]" -v ORS=".\n" 'NR%70==1 {file = sprintf("./tmp/$(patsubst %.txt,%, $< )%04d.txt", NR)} {print > file}' $< 

imported:
    mv odt/*.odt odt/imported/

test: $(SOURCES)
    @echo $(OBJ)
    @echo PREREQUISITES: $^
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do, but the new rule you wrote `%.txt : %.mp3 %.wav %.m4a` means, this rule matches and can build one single txt file _only if_ there exists (or can be built) _ALL_ of the files mp3, wav, _AND_ m4a.  I assume you want to build the txt file from _EITHER_ mp3, wav, _OR_ m4a.  In that case you have to write 3 individual rules, one `%.txt : %.mp3`, and other `%.txt : %.wav`, and a third `%.txt : %.m4a`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use a makefile, when plain old shell can do the job?

```
 WS=ws
 FLAGS="-foo -bar"
 for file in *.mp3 *.wav *.m4a; do
    $WS $FLAGS $file
 done
```

Any particular reason you want to go the `make` way? If it's because you don't want to convert files already converted, you could test the existence of the corresponding txt file.

If you don't want to repeatedly write the same recipe in a makefile because you have a large list of file extensions, you can use a parameterized template recipe and the `eval` function as follows:

```
WS    := @echo ws
FLAGS := --foo --bar

define template =
%.txt: %.$(1)
        $(WS) $(FLAGS) $$<
endef
$(foreach extension,mp3 wav m4a,$(eval $(call template,$(extension))))

BIN := $(wildcard *.mp3 *.wav *.m4a)
TXT := $(addsuffix .txt,$(basename $(BIN)))

all: $(TXT)
```

Comment: I only showed a portion of the makefile. There is a lot of other stuff it does.

Comment: @RickDearman Ok, I've updated my answer with a makefile snippet containing some GNU make magic.

Comment: This fails with:

make: *** No rule to make target '1', needed by 'whisper'. Stop.

Comment: @RickDearman It works perfectly for me. You'd have to show more of your makefile; something in there isn't working.

Comment: I posted the whole file into the question.

Comment: @RickDearman The indenting is inconsistent in your makefile; did you use tabs for all commands in recipes and in the template? A consistently tab-indented version of your makefile works for me.